# rosrun can't find gazebo executable

Tags: gazebo, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed gazebo. Everything went fine but when I went to test it using the commands

`roscore &`

`rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo`

I got the error

`[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named gazebo below`

`/opt/ros/hydro/share/gazebo_ros`

It's strange because tab completion still works and everything appears to be in the correct directories.

Thank you for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125531/rosrun-can%27t-find-gazebo-executable/) by [qazmonk](https://answers.ros.org/users/11576/qazmonk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you build the package? And did you source `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`?
Is there a executable in the bin directory of gazebo_ros?

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qazmonk](https://answers.ros.org/users/11576/qazmonk/) on 2014-02-08**:
It fixed itself when I restarted my computer. Thank you though!